# Compare two C implementations of the same function

Tags: c

Assume I have two folders, `implem_1` and `implem_2`, each containing one file `f.c` implementing the same function *f* in two different ways and the corresponding header `f.h`. The function *f* takes one parameter *x*. I would like to compare the evalutations of the two functions in the two folders over many *x* values, to test whether the implementations match.

The code would be look like this, at the exception that the header files do not define `f_1` and `f_2`, but twice `f`.

```
#include "implem_1/f.h" /* include first  implem f_1 of f */
#include "implem_2/f.h" /* include second implem f_2 of f */

for(x=0; x<1000000; ++x) {
     if(f_1(x)!=f_2(x)) {
         printf("Implementations do not match\n");
         break;
     }
}
```

How can I achieve this without modify anything in the two folders `implem_1` and `implem_2`?

Comment: Since C does not provide namespace, a simpler implementation may be output `f(x)` to 2 different text files and diff them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Compile `implem_1/f.c` with the a preprocessor macro `-Df=f_1`.
2. Compile `implem_2/f.c` with the a preprocessor macro `-Df=f_2`.
3. Change the driver file to:

   ```
   #define f f_1
   #include "implem_1/f.h"
   #undef f
   #define f f_2
   #include "implem_2/f.h" /* include second implem f_2 of f */

   for(x=0; x<1000000; ++x) {
       if(f_1(x)!=f_2(x)) {
            printf("Implementations do not match\n");
            break;
        }
   }
   ```